# TypeScript declare module

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to create local **modules** in my TypeScript (*with Angular 2*) app and then simple reference to any file with importing module like `myApp/components`, `myApp/pipes` etc., not using relative path (*../../../MyComponent*) as I have to do now.

For instance, Angular 2 can be used like this. (*And I haven't found how they make it*)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

---

I did some files like `components.ts`, `templates.ts` etc. where I export files from current section:

```
export * from './menu/item';
export * from './menu/logo';
export * from './article/article';
export * from './article/sidebar';
```

... and then I have one main file `myApp.ts` where I declare modules like so:

```
declare module 'myapp/components' {
    export * from './application/components';
}

declare module 'myapp/templates' {
    export * from './application/templates';
}
```

But this file doesn't generate anything so TS build tells me errors like `...file_path...(4,9): error TS2305: Module ''myapp/components'' has no exported member 'AlfaBeta'.`

Btw. my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.0+ there is a `baseUrl` and `paths` property in `tsconfig.json` that you can use.

In your case, you would want:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "myapp/components": [
                "menu/item",
                "menu/logo",
                "article/article",
                "article/sidebar",
            ],
            "myapp/templates": [
                "templates/*" // whatever files you want to include
            ]
        }
        // etc...
    },
    // etc...
}
```

In `baseUrl` you can specify the base directory (usually the root directory of the project). This allows you to do imports from anywhere in the directory structure as if you were doing an import from the directory specified in `baseUrl`.

For example, with the directory structure...

```
folder1
    - folder2
        - file2.ts
file1.ts
```

...specifying a `"baseUrl": "."` would allow you to import `file1.ts` in `file2.ts` as if you were in the root directory by doing:

```
import * as File1 from "file1";
```

On top of `baseUrl` you can add `paths`. This is useful for you and it must be used with a `baseUrl`. In `paths` you can specify patterns to match and a list of files to include in that pattern. This is illustrated in the [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039#pathMapping) like so:

```
"paths": {
    "pattern-1": ["list of substitutions"],
    "pattern-2": ["list of substitutions"],
    ...
    "pattern-N": ["list of substitutions"]
}
```

Note that this will just make it compile. I believe you'll also have to configure SystemJS in order to get this to work at runtime and that might require using a [barrel](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel) file and setting the path to point to the barrel files.

You can read more about this in the [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039#pathMapping) or read my other related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34926643/188246) that also shows a pre TS 2.0 solution.

Comment: TypeScript 1.8.2 gives me this error when trying to use `baseUrl`: `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'.` and the GitHub issue is tagged with the 2.0 milestone. I'm guessing this didn't actually make it into 1.8.

Comment: @MrHen yes, they changed it to 2.0 now

Answer (score 2):

another way to use TypeScript declare module as below:-

create a file my-module.d.ts

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export default function anyName(arg1: string, arg2: string): MyResponse;
  export interface anyName {
        string: arg;
    }
}
```

and then import as

```
import * as my-module from 'my-module';
```