# TypeScript: how to NOT use relative paths to import classes?

Tags: typescript, angular, electron

I am currently working on an Electron app using TypeScript and Angular2, for which I have created many different classes, all in separate files. In order to make the refactoring of my app easier, I would like to not have to use the relative path when importing those classes.
Right now, to import them, I use this syntax: `import {Trigger} from './../../trigger/ts/trigger.component';`
What I would like to do is use a syntax that looks like this: `import {Trigger} from 'trigger.component';`
Is that possible?

Comment: This has been asked a lot. Hopefully someone replies soon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065880/typescript-declare-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid imports with very long relative paths in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2)

Comment: Good question.  Now that typescript consolidates modules into a single module this is likely to be a common problem.  I'd like typescript to be aware of the AMD configuration but I don't think it is yet.  I bet you can do this with module definitions that import then export the class but that's a high maintenance pain until definition flattening comes around.

Comment: Hot off the press, looks like baseUrl paths might allow this.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: I know it is 6 years later, but I've reviewed this and other q/a around NOT using relative paths in TS project (don't have an issue in JS project) for some months now and can't get it working for the life of me. There's a lot of "you can try this", but no 100% answer. Did anything work for you???

Answer (score 21):

Better to use below configuration in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "...": "reduced for brevity",

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@trigger/*": ["app/trigger/ts/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

For your case, use can do either `import {Trigger} from '@app/trigger/ts/trigger.component';` or `import {Trigger} from '@trigger/trigger.component';` or any level of path you can configure.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one file, for example: components.ts and in that component reference to all components, like:

```
export {Trigger} from '../trigger/ts/trigger.component'
export {Cmp} from '../cmp/ts/cmp.component'
...
```

Than, when you want to load one component, you can do:

```
import {Trigger} from '../components.ts'
```

It is good practice for grouping things.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I sometimes get errors like `EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for TriggerComponent` when including a service. But this service may be included without error in another component... I have to admit I am quite confused...

Comment: Interesting, i did not face that problem. This aggregation of files into one is common thing in Angular2: http, core, common files...

Comment: Really good advice. My path to some file was wrong and I didn't know why. I just put it into another component and now it works, cause I know the path to the component

Answer (score 0):

I created an exporter using [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/) to do just that. I wrote it in C#, but you're welcome to re-write it in whatever language you prefer.

[Here is an example on GitHub](https://github.com/ChuckkNorris/WaitStaffReplacement)

It allows you to have an export file in the root of each component directory which you can import by doing:

`import {LoginPage, HomePage} from '../pages/export'`

or

`import {NavBarComponent, HeroCardComponent} from '../controls/export'`

Say you have multiple components in a specific directory such as:

- app/pages/login-page/login-page.ts
- app/pages/home-page/home-page.ts
- app/controls/nav-bar.ts
- app/controls/hero-card.ts

if you run `scriptcs exporter.cs -- app/pages app/controls`

It will generate an output file called `export.ts` in each of the specified directories with an export statement for each of the classes contained in the directories (which are iterated through recursively)

**exporter.cs**

```
// USAGE
// scriptcs exporter.cs -- app/Templates app/Controls

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

CreateExports();

public void CreateExports() {
    // e.g. 'C:\Apps\MyProject'
    string rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@".\").FullName;

    string exportFileName = "export.ts";
    List<string> exportDirectoryPaths = new List<string>();
    foreach (string argument in Env.ScriptArgs) {
        if (argument.Contains(".ts"))
            exportFileName = argument;
        else
            exportDirectoryPaths.Add(argument);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("File Name:" + exportFileName);
    foreach (string exportDirPath in exportDirectoryPaths) {
        // e.g. 'app\Templates'
        var exportDirPathFixed = exportDirPath.Replace("/", "\\");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exporting -> {0}", exportDirPath));

        List<ExportEntry> exportEntriesToWrite = new List<ExportEntry>();
        // e.g. 'C:\Apps\MyProject\app\Templates' 
        DirectoryInfo exportDir = new DirectoryInfo(rootDir + exportDirPathFixed);
        foreach (FileInfo file in exportDir.EnumerateFiles("*.ts", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            // Don't export the export file ;)
            if (file.Name == exportFileName)
                continue;
            // e.g. toAdd = {
                // RelativepathToExportDirectory = './app/templates/template-one.component'
                // ClassName = 'TemplateOneComponent' (Parsed from file contents, works with interfaces)
            ExportEntry toAdd = CreateExportEntry(file, exportDirPathFixed, rootDir);
            exportEntriesToWrite.Add(toAdd);
        }
        CreateExportFile(exportDir.FullName + "\\" + exportFileName, exportEntriesToWrite);

    }
}


private void CreateExportFile(string exportFilePath, IEnumerable<ExportEntry> exportEntries) {
    string textToWrite = "";
    foreach (ExportEntry entry in exportEntries) {
        textToWrite += entry.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Text: " + Environment.NewLine + textToWrite);
    File.WriteAllText(exportFilePath, textToWrite);
}

// -- Create Export Entry -- //
private ExportEntry CreateExportEntry(FileInfo exportFile, string exportDirPath, string rootDir) {
    ExportEntry toReturn = new ExportEntry() {
        ClassName = GetFirstExportClassName(exportFile),
        RelativepathToExportDirectory = exportFile.FullName.Remove(0, rootDir.Length + exportDirPath.Length).Replace(".ts", ""),
    };
    return toReturn;

}
private string GetFirstExportClassName(FileInfo exportFile) {
    string className = null;
    Regex regular = new Regex(@"(?<=export[\s+]class|interface)[^s+][^\s]+");

    using (StreamReader streamer = new StreamReader(exportFile.OpenRead())) {
        string contents = streamer.ReadToEnd();
        Match componentNameMatch = regular.Match(contents);
        className = componentNameMatch.ToString().Replace("{", "");
    }
    return className;
}

public class ExportEntry {
    public string RelativepathToExportDirectory { get; set; }
    private string _ClassName;
    public string ClassName { 
        get { return _ClassName; }
        set { _ClassName = value.Trim(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the formatted export entry 
    /// e.g. " export {MyComponents} from './Components/my-component.component' "
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString() {
        //      export { AppComponent} from './my-template/my-template.component'
        return String.Format("export {{ {0} }} from '.{1}';", this.ClassName, this.RelativepathToExportDirectory).Replace('\\', '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way of achieving this is by using the *paths* of Typescript v2.*, like it is used here: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

In summary, you can add a index.ts file to a folder, like

```
   export * from './app.component'
   export * from './shared/other.component'
```

and then have webpack to take care of it. 
You should add to your webpack.config.js

```
    const clone = require('js.clone');
    const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
    const TsConfigPathsPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').TsConfigPathsPlugin;
    [...]
    const config = setTypeScriptAlias(require('./tsconfig.json'), {
      [...]
      plugins: [
        new ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            root('./ClientApp')
        ),

        new TsConfigPathsPlugin({
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json'
        }), [...]
```

with these help functions:

```
function setTypeScriptAlias(tsConfig, config) {
  var newConfig = clone(config);
  newConfig = newConfig || {};
  newConfig.resolve = newConfig.resolve || {};
  newConfig.resolve.alias = newConfig.resolve.alias || {};
  var tsPaths = tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths;
  for (var prop in tsPaths) {
    newConfig.resolve.alias[prop] = root(tsPaths[prop][0]);
  }
  return newConfig;
}

function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

And finally define the paths in your tsconfig.js

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "paths": {
        "app":  [ "./ClientApp/app" ] 
    },[...]
```

Then you can just import by the "app" path like

```
   import { AppModule } from 'app';
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it to work by adding the following to `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  ...
}
```

as described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#moduleResolution. It was already in `tsconfig.json`, but apparently that is only used for [IDE integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60410385/594366).