# Typescript can't find a module that has been mapped with SystemJS

Tags: typescript, systemjs, tsc, tsconfig

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) doesn't find the module in this import `import ga from 'googleAnalytics';`

[SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) knows where to find the module, because it has been mapped up front like so:

```
map: {
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'underscore': 'node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js',
    'googleAnalytics': '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'
},
```

How can I provide similar mapping to the `tsc`?

This other question seems to point in a good direction: [How to avoid imports with very long relative paths in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2)

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) 2.0 seems to support the `paths` config for the [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html). Is there a way to download [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) 2.0? Can I give the `path` config an http url (//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js) like I'm doing with [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)? If there is no way to download [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) 2.0, how can I achieve what I want with the current version?

**Edit**

The specific error I get is: "Cannot find module 'ga'".

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "front-end/node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think Typescript 2 has been released yet. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tags

Comment: Indeed it doesn't look like it has been released.

Comment: what happens if you import it like this `import {ga} from 'googleAnalytics';`

Comment: Same error. Whether I do `import ga`, `import {ga}` or `import *` doesn't matter, because it doesn't find the module `googleAnalytics`. The reason I get the error `Cannot find module 'ga'` is because @jasonszhao told me to rename `googleAnalytics` to `ga` (see the only answer below). I admit this is confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you understand that in case of typescript compilation transpiler is looking for definitly type files. He needs to know type definition of external module. I case you have active nodejs module resolution (you have) and you use a non-relative path (you do) you have to add to your project node_modules directory (maybe you already have one) and to this directory add googleAnalytics.d.ts file or you can create  node_modules/googleAnalytics directory and then add there index.d.ts. Definition types for google analytics can be downloaded from DefintelyTyped [repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/google.analytics)

more info about module resolution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

EDIT: according your comment maybe you will have to add modul export to google definition file

```
declare module 'googleAnalytics' {
    export = UniversalAnalytics;
}
```

Comment: Manually creating a folder in `node_modules` is a very bad practice. You should rarely (if not never) have modify this folder. The typescript compiler also looks for [ambiant module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries), which is what @jasonszhao proposed, but it seems like the google analytics type definition doesn't export anything.

Comment: Excellent i didn't know it.

Comment: As a follow up to your edit: you are right, but it would be `export = ga` instead of `export = UniversalAnalytics `. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be worked around with [Typescript Type Definitions](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files).

To use the definition:

1. Put the type definition in your directory. Premade ones are provided by [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/).
2. Add this line to the .ts file that needs to import Google Analytics:

   ```js
   /// <reference path="ga.d.ts" />
   ```

---

**Update**

It did work for me when I ran `tsc`. Sorry I forgot to add:

3. Refactor to `ga` in your `import`s and SystemJS mapping.

This does not make the compiler know that it needs to check the SystemJS file, but just acts like a placeholder for the module that you import, so that no error is thrown and we can actually resolve the module during runtime with SystemJS.

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but I still tried it (and it didn't work). How is this `d.ts` file suppose to tell the `tsc` that to find the `googleAnalytics` module, it needs to look at the SystemJs mapping (or at least have the same mapping)? Maybe it doesn't need to know the mapping, but only find a corresponding `d.ts` file, but how would the `tsc` compiler link a custom module name such as `googleAnalytics` to `ga.d.ts`?

Comment: It's still not working, maybe because the `d.ts` doesn't declare a module? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/google.analytics/ga.d.ts

Comment: I edited my question with the additional information.