# Angular 2 paths setting

Tags: angular, typescript

For what keyword should I look to learn how to configure my Angular app to be able to load my internal modules with following:

`import { MyModule } from 'cool/short/path';`

instead of:

`import { MyModule } from './../../../modules/MyModle/my-module';`

I went through some tutorial mentioning how to configure **whole** app to use some kind of absolute path marking, but is it possible to configure single module in such manner? As a notable example I'd mention Angular modules, which are always referred with `@` and same path from whatever project location.

Comment: If you are using TypeScript 2.0+ there is a good answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, what you're asking is a property of TypeScript compiler options. Look at this [document describing `baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url).

Since we're talking about `import ...` instruction, it's unrelated to Angular. You'll need to set it in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Your "non-relative paths" (those without `..`) will be resolved starting the `baseUrl`. So, technically, they are still relative. The difference is instead of being relative to the *current file*, they will be relative to the *directory you specified*. You will still be able to use `..`-based imports if you want. You can even mix the import styles within the same file...

Comment: Yeah, I know this feature is not related to Angular itself, Angular is just an example here :) Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

OP here again, I'd like to mention one important gotcha in "non-relative paths". As [Igor Soloydenko answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46680858/2759473) mentions `tsconfig.json` file, for myself it worked correctly after modifying `tsconfig.app.json` file, which in fact extends base `tsconfig.json`, but even though only working from app file level my changes were effective.