# Angular2, TypeScript and Visual Studio Code absolute path configuration

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

As already explained to me in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680614/angular-2-paths-setting) question (thank you by the way), i can use TS configuration file to provide `baseUrl` and `paths` to be able to reduce nonsense paths like `../../../../someModule` to way shorter, aliased versions like `@AliasPath/someModule`. So, I modified my `tsconfig.app.json` (please note, I modified .app.json config file, not main tsconfig.json in root folder) file with following line:

```
....
"baseUrl": "./",
....
"paths": {
  "@services/*" : ["app/services/*", "src/app/services/*"]
}
```

In code I try to import one service by:
`import { CommunicationService } from "@services/communication.service";`

Project is building fine, but TypeScript is unable to recognize my defined path aliases, marking them with red squiggle line:

[image]

And reporting missing files in problem tab:

[image]

The question is, how can I instruct TypeScript (because I assume it's TypeScript issue) about my paths aliases?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with VS Code as you can see on the following link for example (it is one of many):
[VSCode ignores paths in tsconfig.app.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21473)

But I have found a workaround for me, since I had the same problem. I just installed the extention **TypeScript Importer**. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As of TypeScript 3.1, the `paths` configuration must be in a file called `tsconfig.json`. It will not be picked up by vscode if it is in `tsconfig.app.json` (but `tsc -p tsconfig.app.json` will obviously work).

To make sure a TS file is part of the right `tsconfig`, run the `TypeScript: Go to project configuration` command in VS Code. This should open the tsconfig with `paths` set

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me in my angular project.