# How can I import file from another directory that is at the same level?

Tags: typescript

How to import stuff from a file that is in another directory but at the same level?
For example: i am in file 1 of folder 1 and want to import stuff from file 2 from folder 2. How to do that? Currently i get the error that the module cannot be found.

Current tree:

```
-ComponentsFolder
    -Folder1
       -File1
    -Folder2 
       -File2
```

Answer (score 8):

You simply construct relative path from one file to another. Like in in OS.

```
import '../Folder2/File2';
```

But you should avoid relative imports because it might get painful really quickly. Consider this: `../../../../dir1/dir2/dir3`. Pretty bad, isn't it?
There is really good tutorial how to avoid relative paths and use absolute paths. Just a few configuration changes and you get `dir1/dir2/dir3`
[How to avoid imports with very long relative paths in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2/34926643)

Answer (score 0):

Simply move back one folder and then go into the folder, so in file 1 get it like this:

```
import '../Folder2/File2';
```