# Load template/styles using absolute path

Tags: angular

How to load a component template/styles using absolute paths (i.e. from another module) ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  templateUrl: 'shared-module/components/another-shared-component/component.html',
  styleUrls: ['shared-module/components/another-shared-component/component.scss']
})
```

I have tries using `/`, `~/` and just starting with the module name but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. There was an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4974), but:

> won't implement since absolute absolute paths have different meaning for AoT vs JIT. [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4974#issuecomment-407630605)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried start from `/src/...`? This works for me:

```
styleUrls: ['/src/shared-module/components/another-shared-component/component.scss']
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on Angular 9.2.4

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the relative path operators `./` and `../`? If the `component.html` was two levels (folders) above it would be:

`templateUrl: '../../shared-module/components/another-shared-component/component.html'`

If in current directory but different subfolder:

`templateUrl: './shared-module/components/another-shared-component/component.html'`

Comment: The `../` will work but it will be a long path to get to the component folder, that's why I was looking for an absolute approach.

Comment: Maybe [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2) will help

Comment: This is for TypeScript module system; It seems Angular does not take that into account (though it would make sense if they did).