# TypeScript module resolution issue with AngularCLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a project created with AngularCLI.

- AngularCLI - version 1.6.7
- Angular - version 5.1.1
- TypeScript - version 2.5.3
- WebPack - version 3.1.0

After going through the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) for TSConfig module resolution I wanted to create custom mapping to avoid long relative paths .

I've also checked this SO question but it didn't help me either:

[How to avoid imports with very long relative paths in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2/34926643)

(Using Visual Studio Code)

My project structure is like:

```
node_modules
src
 |__ app
      |__ utilities
              |__ services
                     |__ event.service.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@services/*": [
            "src/app/utilities/services/*"
        ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

I've tried many different combinations but I can't get my import to work like:

`import { EventService } from '@services/event.service';`

It always gives me an error `Cannot find module @services/event.service`
But if I import it with relative path it works perfectly, so can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with these custom mappings ?

Edit: 
I've managed to get it to work by changing

`"moduleResolution": "node"` to `"moduleResolution": "classic"`

however then `"@angular/core"` or any other `"@angular"` modules stop working. I've ran into this github issue and I am unsure if there's a workaround at the moment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: What happens when you try this without the @ in the paths config? I mean, just get rid of the @. Does it work then?

Comment: It doesn't work either, I've tried with many variations.

Comment: What is your Webpack configuration?  Specifically do you have this same path defined in resolve.alias?  Also where do you see that error?  In your editor or during the build?