# In Typescript, how do I overried index.d.ts provided with a 3rd party lib with my own?

Tags: typescript, overriding, typescript-typings

I'm using a 3rd party Javascript library that comes with an index.d.ts file. However, that file is not compatible with my version of TS. I've made a fix that works for me and submitted it to the library creator. In the meanwhile, I'd like to use this fix. I need to commit it to VCS for my entire team to use. `node_modules` folder is not committed to VCS, its content is installed on checkout, so I can't just overwrite / get rid of the file provided by 3rd party.

Where do I put my custom .d.ts file and how do I tell typescript to use it over supplied one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `paths` option in in `tsconfig` to map any module to a custom definition file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions" : {
        ..
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "some_module": ["custom.d.ts"]
        }
    },
}
```

This feature is usually used with wild cards to map custom paths but it can be used for specific modules as well. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2).