# import { * } from "@angular" instead of "angular2"

Tags: typescript, angular, commonjs

I am little confused here in angular2. Many example show like

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
```

But actually in `node_module` there is `angular2`directory exists. So logically it should be

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core"
```

What is the difference between this two ?

Comment: Angular apps are modular. They consist of many files each dedicated to a purpose.

Angular itself is modular. It is a collection of library modules each made up of several, related features that we'll use to build our application.

When we need something from a module, we import it. Here we import the Angular Component decorator function from @angular/core because we need it to define our component.

app/app.component.ts (import)

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

Comment: @mayur, I think you may have misunderstood the question. The OP is not asking what or why the import functions are used, but they are asking about the use of the `"@"` symbol. The answer below from Gunter explains this. Check out the changelog in the link they posted.

Answer (score 9):

That's a change that was introduced with the update from beta.17 to rc.0

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

Comment: Any idea why the switch?

Comment: @RyanRahlf AFAIK there are name restrictions for namespaces on NPM and the `@` is one of these. They also don't want different namespaces for different Angular versions, just one for everything Angular.

Comment: what if you use a module below **beta.17** in a **r.c.** project? Which syntax do you use then?

Comment: What beta 17 module? I'm sure Angular2 modules won't work together if versions differ. Perhaps with some luck you can make something work if ther versions only differ a bit, but there were always so many changes that it's very unlikely.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. If I import only one component like `import { Component } from '@angular/core'` instead of `import * from '@angular/core'`, will it affect on the effectiveness of the code, not at the first glance ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that. I'm not really using TS myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export/33307487#33307487 also doesn't say anything about effectiveness. I guess it won't make a difference.