# Angular 2 import { * } from “@angular” instead of “angular2”

Tags: angular, typescript

What is difference between import {*} from "@angular" and "angular2"? Which is better to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import { \* } from "@angular" instead of "angular2"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136985/import-from-angular-instead-of-angular2)

Comment: That was not satisfactory answer. If i use @angular, it internally uses gulp as task manager, and i want to use grunt. How i can do that?

Comment: "@angular internally uses gulp as task manager..." please elaborate it, because I think there is no link between these 2.