# typescript: import all classes not into new namespace

Tags: typescript

I have several classes in `all.ts` module:

```
export class TemperatureSensor {
    temperature: number;
}

export class Chasis {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    ambientTemperature: TemperatureSensor
}

export class Computer {
    model: string;
    serial: string;
    chasis: Chasis;
}
```

In another module I need to import all of them - I use

```
import * as models from 'all';
```

And I can access classes with `new models.Computer()` as the example.

Quesion: how can I import all classes from `all.ts` without namespace? So I'd like to use `new Computer()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deconstruct as in

```
import * as models from 'all';
const {Computer} = models;
```

Comment: I don't see the point. Isn't this just a verbose way of doing a named import?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export/33307487#33307487) for the possible ways to import.

Your best option is to use named imports that specify what you need in the file:

```
import {Computer} from './all';

new Computer();
```