# You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The code below gives

> Uncaught Error: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined

**List.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect, bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux';
import PostList from '../components/PostList'; // Component I wish to wrap with actions and state
import postList from '../Actions/PostList' //Action Creator defined by me

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return state.postsList
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({"postsList":postList},dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**PostList.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const PostList = (props) => {
    return <div>List</div>
}
```

Please help me with a solution?

Comment: check Postlist import

Comment: There is no problem with PostList import

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to either export default or import {PostList} from '../components/PostList';

Comment: yea. Am pretty sure that exporting in this fashion is enough to import anywhere else

Comment: You are not default exporting `PostList`, so you will have to import it as `import {PostList} from '../components/PostList';` (With curly braces). Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33307487/4248342) for more info:

Comment: Thanks @HardikModha

Comment: Don't be so sure.. ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are doing `import PostList from '../components/PostList';` so you need to use `export default` in your PostList.js file.

Otherwise you need to do `import { PostList } from '../components/PostList';`.

To whoever is interested, here is a nice article about es6 import/export syntax: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: In my case, I had copied the code from another component and changed everything except the name in the `propTypes` declaration

Answer (score 7):

Not related to the asker specifically, but if you're facing this error, it's worth to check if you have the connect() syntax right:

```
const PreloadConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Preload);

export default PreloadConnect;
```

Note that *Preload*, is passed as a IIFE parameter.

Answer (score 4):

More details can be found [here](https://haodong.io/redux-testing-invariant-violation-error).

There might be three reasons, that are summarized as follows:

> - Circular dependencies between components
> - Wrong usage of `export` and `export default` then imported the wrong way
> - Used the connect function wrongly, passed the wrong parameters

In my case is was Circular dependencies, and the [circular-dependency-plugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin) helped me fix it.

Comment: spent a couple of hours and found `Circular dependencies between components` caused that issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Expo server that sometimes doesn't catch filesaves on Windows (probably) and it was seening old version of the component I've tried to connect (I had no export there yet probably). Re-saving my component without really touching anything fixed the issue.

Restarting Expo server with cleaned cache would probably help as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of the usage of enums (TypeScript).
Try without enums in your code.

Reason : Enums can go undefined during runtime.

[Link to Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418124/enum-type-not-defined-at-runtime)

Hope it solves your problem :)