# Enum type not defined at runtime

Tags: typescript

I have a problem where the Typescript compiler compiles my code successfully, yet the runtime gives me undefined type errors.

In my app I created a `types.ts` file with some things shared between multiple other ts files. It contains a string enum like:

```
enum MyEnum {
  One = "one";
  Two = "two";
}
```

When I define it like this. The compiler lets me use it in other ts files, and appears to be happy. However, at runtime I get the error "MyEnum is not defined".

I know of two ways to solve this:

1. Define the enum in the file where it is used. But I don't think this will solve anything for other files that want to use it.
2. Use "export" in the types.ts file, and import every type explicitly everywhere it is used.

I am quite new to Typescript, and I feel I might be misunderstanding something fundamental.

First, I don't get why the Typescript compiler happily compiles my code if there's going to be a runtime error. I would understand it if I had used the `declare` keyword, telling the compiler that something *should* be available at runtime, but in this case I don't see why it should assume that the enum comes from anywhere else then the types.ts file.

Second, I would like to define types somewhere globally in my app and have them be available everywhere without having to import them every time I used them. How do I accomplish this? Or is this maybe considered bad practice?

I am using Typescript 2.6 and my config looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext"],

    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "removeComments": true /* Do not emit comments to output. */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,

    "plugins": [{ "name": "tslint-language-service" }],
    "skipLibCheck": true // because firebase-sdk has wrong type files now (Nov 18)
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

Comment: The enum will be transpiled as an object. If you are using as a node app you must export and import it in the files where you want to use. If you don't, it would only work in a browser environment where a script with your transpiled file containing the enum is placed before all other files that reference the object.

Comment: OK the object makes sense to me. I was wondering why this only occurred in my server code and not the web client. But could you explain a bit more about how this works in the browser, or provide a link to more info? Do enums become globally declared variables in a browser environment?

Comment: No, you have to put a script tag with the file transpiled with the enum object _before_ the script tag that references it ... <script src="myscriptwiththeenum.js"><script/> ... and after that <script src="myscriptthatusestheenum.js"><script/> ...<script src="myotherscriptthatusestheenum.js"><script/>. If  you use webpack, browserify or other tool like that just use the import statement  and you will not have to concern with the script order

Comment: Ah ok. But technically still a global variable then, just maybe hidden somewhere :) I'm using the Typescript variant of [CRA](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) so I guess it's dealt with already. I still wonder what a nice solution is on the server side. By using an enum (and the export) I am forced to now also export and import all of the other interface and type declarations that live in that file...

Comment: I've been using `/// <reference path="RelativePathToTypeScriptFile/TypeScriptFile.ts"/>` at the top of the dependent TypeScript file to reference classes and functions and they work fine.  However, for some reason it doesn't work for enums!

Comment: Disregard my last comment about `reference path` not working for enums; I forgot to include a reference to the resultant JavaScript file in my `BundleConfig.cs` file for my MVC project.  This was the cause of the problem for me.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's another way you can do this. If you don't want to export your enum you can define it as a *const enum*

```
const enum MyEnum {
   One = "one";
   Two = "two";
}
```

These are inlined by the compiler and are completely removed during compilation.

Comment: Thanks, I had since discovered that too. I also use it for all enums that I export. But I forgot that this question didn't have an accepted answer yet...

Comment: Beware of using this solution if you need to parse a string into the enum.  I now get `'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment.` for the expression: `(<any>MyEnum)[myString] === MyEnum.One`.

Comment: @MattArnold the error is that you can only use string literals to index a const enum. That error is probably being hidden due to the fact you're casting to *any*, something I would generally try to avoid. It may be that *string literal types* are more suited to your use-case.

Comment: @nukefusion Ah that's disappointing; I thought the whole point of having the `[]` syntax as an alternative to `.` was to allow the dynamic access of members via a variable.  In my scenario, I didn't need the `const` in the end anyway, I had just forgotten to include the enum file in my `BundleConfig.cs`.  I did still need the `<any>` cast to make it work though (which seems like a bit of a hack!).

Comment: I had this same issue. When I tried making them into const enums it still didn't work. I had to wipe away my build output directory (+build cache?) then build.

Comment: using `const enum` did work.. but why does this work instead of using just `enum`?

Comment: I stopped using enums altogether. The added complexity is not worth it for me. I seem to be able to do everything with string literals and it appears cleaner too.

Answer (score 72):

In my case of `undefined` enum, it turned out it's because of circular import:

`export enum A {...}` defined in file `a.ts`,
`export const b = ...` defined in file `b.ts`;

`import {A} from './a.ts'` in `b.ts`,
while `import {b} from './b.ts'` in `a.ts`.

The error was gone after removing circular imports.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Curious, how did you come to this solution?

Comment: Whew! Anyone know if this is expected behavior?

Comment: This answer literally saved my evening

Comment: This year was not ending well until I found your answer -  hours of tangling with this exact issue - fixed in 2 min once I saw this - thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem when imported re-exported enum. It caused runtime error.

layout.ts

```
export enum Part { Column, Row }
```

index.ts

```
export * from './layout'
```

component.ts

```
import { Part } from '../entities' // This causes error
import { Part } from '../entities/layout' // This works
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same error and re-export is currently only viable way to approach this so I'm a bit stuck

Comment: No. You can stop using enums.

Comment: This must be what's going on for us since we often utilize this pattern. I also wasn't sure if this was potentially related to how SWC resolves imports/usages, as if they were getting shaken out because they aren't directly utilized but instantiated in some POJOs we have which ends up throwing an error that the property doesn't exist on undefined. I'm surprised this isn't more widespread or that there must be an issue opened up somewhere. I'm just not certain if it's a special case or related to some circular dependency or tree shaking 

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue because I used declare in

```
export declare enum SomeEnum
```

Instead of

```
export enum SomeEnum
```

Comment: Do you know why using the declare keyword causes this issue? I am unable to import from a package because of it.

Comment: declare is appended when typescript is compiled. so my problem is still the same.

Answer (score 5):

For us it turned out that simply restarting the application solved the problem. (Nativescript app)

Comment: This worked for me too. I had created a new enum file and I believe the app had yet to compile the file and as a result returned undefined in React

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving a similar error message while importing an enum from another project of mine. I was exporting the enum, but it was not declared as a "const". I updated my enum in my other project to the below code and it worked  as expected.

```
export const enum MyEnum {
  One = 'one',
  Two = 'two'
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me. No clue why const is required.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and it went away as soon as I used the export keyword, i.e.

```
export enum MyEnum {
  One = "one";
  Two = "two";
}
```

And make sure you import it in the files where you are using it as well, i.e.

```
import { MyEnum } from '../types.ts';
```

I found that when I declared the enum without the export keyword, I could still reference the enum without importing it in other files without a compiler error - it was only at runtime the undefined exception was then thrown.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the comments below the question you see that I already got this far :) I am now mainly wondering if there is no way to globally define types in the app without having to export/import everything, because it is really cumbersome to do this for all types. I guess you could just put all the enums in a separate file and only export/import that. This way all other types are still globally available and you don't need to write all of the boilerplate to use them across the app.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what IDE are you using? With Visual Studio Code, when you type out the name of the enum, VS Code will automatically generate the import statement for you, which saves a considerable amount of time when coding, and helps to keep a smooth uninterrupted flow. I was originally using JetBrains WebStorm but found I was more productive in the Visual Studio Code IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my case, when I add a new enum to `enum.ts` file like this:

`enum.ts`:

```js
enum RotateMode {
  UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN',
  OPTIMIZE = 'OPTIMIZE',
  ROTATE_FOREVER = 'ROTATE_FOREVER'
}

export { RotateMode };
```

I didn't run `tsc` to compile this file again. This cause the `enum.js` file doesn't have the `RotateMode` enum

`enum.js`:

```js
// old file doesn't have the RotateMode enum
```

Then, I import the `RotateMode` enum to my `index.ts` file:

```js
import { RotateMode } from './enum';

console.log(`RotateMode: ${JSON.stringify(RotateMode)}`);
```

The result is:

```sh
RotateMode: undefined
```

Somehow, the `import` syntax will import from `.js` file with high priority.

So, **DON'T forget to compile the ts file after you add something new**

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party but beware of any @ts-ignore lines in the files blamed by the error stack.

My issue was that, after a pretty big refactoring, the import to the enum was cleaned by an IDE shortcut and the compiler couldn't detect it as missing because of the ts-ignore annotation which was targeted at something else (alas, on the same line).

Comment: And how did you solve it?