# Redux/React. You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I see this topic [You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324317/you-must-pass-a-component-to-the-function-returned-by-connect-instead-received/42329949), but it's does not about my case.

So, I cannot undurstand what is the wrong with my presentation/container connection?

I connect they one to each other, but I get an error: `You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined`

/* COMPONENT */

```
import React from 'react';
import AddTodo from '../../Actions/AddTodo'
import TodoFormAdd from '../../Containers/TodoFormAdd'

class TodoForm extends React.Component{   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector('input').input.value = '';   
        TodoFormAdd(this.props.store, this.input.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form id="tp" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" />
                <button type="submit">Add todos</button>
            </form>
        );  
    }
}

export default TodoForm;
```

/* CONTAINER */

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoForm from '../Components/TodoForm/TodoForm'
import AddTodo from '../Actions/AddTodo'

let TodoFormAdd = (store, input) => store.dispatch(AddTodo(input));

export default connect(TodoFormAdd)(TodoForm);
```

Comment: are your sure the path `import TodoForm from '../Components/TodoForm/TodoForm'` is correct

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

The problem had been in the closer of invoke these two codes in one time of running.

So the chain is the next:

1. We start the component `TodoForm` that also try to import `TodoFormAdd`;
2. `TodoFormAdd` does not already got the parameters to work and start begins to crash.
3. Then `TodoForm` cannot finish compilation themself and aslo crash.

And that it. So I just delete `import TodoFormAdd` in `TodoForm` and and everything became good.

Thank's for all for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import TodoForm from '../Components/TodoForm/TodoForm'.
```

1) Is `TodoForm` defined?, console.log it
2) Is `TodoForm` component? go through you file structure and see the file, is file exists? is component exists in this file?

Comment: 1. Yes, defined. It's strange, but console.log really shows `undefined` state for `TodoForm ` from `TodoFormAdd` container.
2. Yes, `TodoForm` is a component.

Moreover, if the file will does not exist, the compilation will be not completed.

So this is must be an another reason, why we still get `undefined` for `TodoForm` component calling from `TodoFormAdd`

Comment: @Max Wolfen Okay try to export yur component like this `connect(null, { TodoFormAdd 
 })(TodoForm);`

Answer (score 1):

From `react-redux` API Doc:

> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])

`connect(..)` takes `mapStateToProps` function as its first argument, and your `TodoFormAdd` doesn't seem like a valid mapStateToProps, which should take the `store` state as its input, and return a plain object

> The results of `mapStateToProps` must be a plain object which will a plain object, which will be merged into the component’s props

I recommend reading the redux [doc and its examples](https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list) multiple times, until you understand the concepts well.

I won't write the whole code for you, but in your case, TodoFormAdd seems redundant.

Just make `TodoForm` component a container (i.e. 'connected') component, and you get `dispatch(..)` for free passed through props!

It will look similar to this:

```js
class TodoForm extends React.Component {
    ...

    handleSubmit(e) {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector('input').input.value = '';   
        dispatch(AddTodo(input));
    }

    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  // your mapStateToProps return object
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoForm);
```