# No export in component? React

Tags: reactjs

I'm so so sorry for wasting people's time on such a stupid error. But it's driving me crazy, I don't know why its occurring. To my knowledge I've done everything correct. So I'm trying to import a component called `NewSiteNav` into my `NewSite` component. The path I am directing to is correct, I even know because I'm using the VSC tool that helps you autocomplete path selections. I have the import written correctly, have tried it with and without these `{}` and I have exported the `NewSiteNav` correctly using both `export default class...` at the beginning and `export default NewSiteNav` at the end. Please help

`NewSiteNav` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class NewSiteNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar>
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                                <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`NewSite` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NewSiteNav } from '../components/NewSiteNav';

class NewSite extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NewSiteNav />
        <div className="lander">
          <h1>New Site</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NewSite;
```

Answer (score 3):

try to change

```
import { NewSiteNav } from '../components/NewSiteNav';
```

to

```
import NewSiteNav from '../components/NewSiteNav';
```

Comment: When I do this I get the following error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `NewSiteNav`.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your child component `NewSiteNav` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

   export class NewSiteNav extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                    <div>
                        <Navbar>
                            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                                </Nav>
                            </Navbar.Collapse>
                        </Navbar>
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default NewSiteNav
```

If it doesn't help you sound check you `export/import` files on circling loop. Maybe some of them are still not loaded when you try to use it in other file. Check this post:  [Redux/React. You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590362/redux-react-you-must-pass-a-component-to-the-function-returned-by-connect-inst)

Comment: When I do this I still get the original error `./src/containers/NewSite.js
Attempted import error: 'NewSiteNav' is not exported from '../components/NewSiteNav'.`

Comment: Okay, so in this case check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590362/redux-react-you-must-pass-a-component-to-the-function-returned-by-connect-inst answer describing. The person there has the same problem as you

Answer (score 0):

When you make

```
export default class NewSiteNav extends Component
```

you can import it with whatever name you want

```
import foooName from './path'
```

but when you you make

```
export class NewSiteNav extends Component
```

make sure that you import it with the correct name

```
import newStireNave from './path'
```

if this solution doesn't work for you try to change extends from Component to React.Component

```
export default class NewSiteNav extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return (
                    <div>
                        <Navbar>
                            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                                </Nav>
                            </Navbar.Collapse>
                        </Navbar>
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I do this it gets rid of the original error and compiles. But then i am presented with this: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `NewSiteNav`.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to export your component like this

`class NewSiteNav extends Component { ... }
export default NewSiteNav`

And import like this

`import NewSiteNav from '../components/NewSiteNav';`

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import?answertab=active#tab-top) to more explanation about ES6 import.