# IE11 React.memo + react-redux connect issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I am trying to memoize redux-connected component using React.memo.
My code works normally in major browsers but IE throws error:

```
You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"$$typeof":60115,"compare":null}
```

Component code:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = ({ some, prop }) => (
  <div>Some React</div>
);

const MyComponentMemoized = memo(MyComponent);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  some: someSelector(state),
  prop: propSelector(state),
});

const MyComponentMemoizedAndConnected = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponentMemoized);
export default MyComponentMemoizedAndConnected;
```

Notes about app setup: using webpack with babel-loader, babel config:

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        corejs: '3.6',
        "targets": {
          "chrome": "58",
          "ie": "11"
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
```

Comment: does it work if you remove memo?

Comment: I found in my search result that this error may occur due to 3 reasons. Circular dependencies between components, Wrong usage of export and export default then imported the wrong way, and Used the connect function wrongly, passed the wrong parameters. You can try to check for it may help to fix the issue. [Helpful article](https://haodong.io/redux-testing-invariant-violation-error) and [Helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324317/you-must-pass-a-component-to-the-function-returned-by-connect-instead-received)

Comment: @ducmai yep, it works without memo; and just memoized component without connect works also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found this bug disappeared after I removed `'react-hot-loader/patch'` from my webpack `entry` arr. Don't know why it happens, but hope it will save someones time

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone run into this issue, check the order you are using `memo` and `connect`.

For example, using `compose` from `recompose`:

```js
compose(
    React.memo,
    connect(mapStateToProps),
)(MyComponent);
```

`React.memo` should be used before `connect`.