# Type of exported object not recognized in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ES6 and TypeScript. We have refactored some of our code to ES6 but we a trying out if it wouldn't be better to switch to TypeScript instead for writing more maintainable code easier.

If have the following, simplified ES6 module `config.js`

```
export default {
  logger: require('winston'),
  somethingelse: 'text'
}
```

I import this module everywhere throughout my project, such as in `app.js`:

```
import * as config from '../../../../config'
const logger = config.logger
...
```

As far as I understand, typing is optional in TypeScript and ES6 code should just run fine if I just rename the files from `.js` to `.ts`. Please correct me if that was a wrong assumption I had. However, I get this error when I compile:

```
/project/app.ts(7,23): Property 'logger' does not exist on type 'typeof \"/project/config\"'.
```

So that means, I **have** to declare a type? So then I went ahead and declared an interface for the exported object.

`config.js`:

```
interface IConfig {
  logger: any;
  somethingelse: string;
}

const defaultConfig: IConfig = {
     logger: winston,
     text: 'text'
}

export default defaultConfig
```

But I'm still getting the above compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `* as ...` from your import declaration. Try this:

```
import config from '../../../../config'
const logger = config.logger
...
```

> See this answer for more information [Typescript export vs. default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export#33307487)