# Why so many angular4 project use export class xxx rather than export default class xxx?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know what's the difference between `export class xxx` and `export default class xxx`.

But I saw many `angular4` project use `export class xxx` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'call-record',
  templateUrl: './collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collection.component.css']
})
export class collection {

}
```

I think if there is one class or whatever to export, use `export default xxx` should be better?

So I can import it like this: `import xxx from './somewhere'`

not this: `import {xxx} from './somewhere'`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307487/2545680

Comment: There's also some issues around using `default` keyword when using with angular-cli, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3826

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript export vs. default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export)

Comment: @LarsMonty @Maximus I don't think my question is duplicated. As I said, I __know__ what's the difference between `export xxx` and `export default xxx`. My question's point is why so many projects of angular4 use `export  xxx` not `export default xxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with maintainability:

- If you refactor `xxx` in the `somewhere` module, it will not be renamed in the file that imports the module.
- If you eventually need to export more useful information(not only concrete class but also `types`, `interfaces`, `constants`) from the file then you must use `export { ConcreteClass, SomeType, ISomeInterface, SomeConstant}`.
- The discoverability of the default export is very poor, and you cannot intelligently distinguish whether a module has a default export
- Editor/IDE automatic completion
- If you use CommonJs like this `const {default} = require('./somewhere')`, you most likely want to rename the default export.
- Prevent spelling errors. If you use `import Foo from './foo'` during development, you won't get any spelling errors. Others might write `import foo from'./foo'` like this.

For the above reasons, the default export should be avoided.