# How can I convert from default export to normal export in typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export), and [this one](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html), and figured it is probably not a good idea to use default export. However, when I was trying to change my code, I ran to an issue: there some variables/objects/functions are not clearly defined to be export. For example:

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import { Controller } from './controller';

const controller = new Controller();

express.Router()
    .post('/', controller.create)
    .get('/', controller.all)
    .get('/:id', controller.byId);

export default express.Router();
```

I wonder how can I declare the export so it won't use the default export. I tried

```
export = express.Router
```

But I feel that is not a good practice as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You could just do, `export default { router: express.Router() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default exports are not bad if you use them right. In this example it is totally fine.

But if you want to give it a name, just assign it to a variable.

```
export const router = express.Router();
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!