# React-TypeScript: How to import component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is my react components structure (Using TypeScript):

```
-App.tsx

  -NewRequestForm.tsx

    -EmployeeInfo.tsx

    -AssetInfo.tsx
```

I am trying to import EmployeeInfo & AssetInfo in NewRequestForm, but while using import statement both components are not visible, but I can see Prop & States interfaces.

[image]

Please suggest how child components can be imported in my NewFormRequest.tsx

**AssetInfo.tsx (child1)**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface AssetInfoProps {}
export interface AssetInfoState {}

export default class AssetInfo extends React.Component<AssetInfoProps, 
AssetInfoState> {
  constructor(props: AssetInfoProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  public render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

**EmployeeInfo.tsx (Child2)**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface EmployeeInfoProps {}
export interface EmployeeInfoState {}

export default class EmployeeInfo extends React.Component<EmployeeInfoProps, 
EmployeeInfoState> {
  constructor(props: EmployeeInfoProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  public render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

**NewRequestForm.tsx (Parent)**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {} from './EmployeeInfo';
import {} from './AssetInfo';

export interface NewRequestFormProps {}

export default class NewRequestForm extends 
React.Component<NewRequestFormProps, any> {
  public render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `default` keyword for exporting the `EmployeeInfo`

Comment: Thanks Murat, It worked. Any explanation behind removing 'default'  keyword ?

Comment: @SandeepNandey You would import a default export without `{}`, but you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307487/4467208