# How to configure TypeScript to throw an error/warning for incorrect import statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, visual-studio-code

I am working on converting a large application from JavaScript (Backbone and Angular 1) to TypeScript. When we convert a file that is used by other files we understand that we have to update the import statements in those other JavaScript files so that it imports the new TypeScript file correctly. Our syntax update in fake-file.js is as follows.

Before:
    `import OurService from 'our.service';`

After: 
    `import { OurService } from 'our.service';`

I understand that this is an easy change but TypeScript is new to many developers and there have been problems with people missing some of these import statements or forgetting to change them all together resulting in some issues during runtime. I have looked into compiler options but I do not see any that would fix this issue but I could be misinterpreting them.

Question: Is there a way to configure the compiler (or a Visual Studio Code plugin) to throw a warning or an error to prevent this from happening?

Comment: So you are looking to force a [**named import**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307487/6925187). I am not aware that there exists a configuration for that already. But for instance you could write [your own tslint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/).

Comment: @HaaLeo Thank you for your comment. I will look into TSLint, I have never heard of it before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that I understood your requirement and possibly you need to adapt a linting process and consequently I would suggest the following tools (which I also use in my project):

1. Airbnb Javascript style guide (your import statement concern-https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules). These are a well-defined set of standards defined for any JS application (including ES).
2. [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). You can run ESLint from the terminal and configure it for your project that highlights warning/errors in your code. If this looks complicated, you can generate the tslint document for your entire project in the [website](https://eslint.org/demo/) itself. Click on `rules configuration` and configure the ES rules for your project. There are some `import` related rules too.
   PS: Feel free to add your comments.