# TestCafe Default vs Named Classes

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Looking over the Page Object model for TestCafe I noticed that all of the classes are flagged with `default` rather than typical named classes.

http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/using-page-model.html

I'm wondering what the reason is behind this, does it somehow assist in the passing of test controller and queuing of browser actions?

> TestCafe allows you to avoid passing the test controller to the method explicitly. Instead, you can import t to the page model file. [link](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-controller)

I would like to avoid using default classes as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export) suggests but I want to know what the trade-offs are specific to TestCafe.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not required to use the `default` keyword for TestCafe. Moreover, it does not affect test passing or a browser's operation. It's just a way of exporting/importing a class from a module with one class. If you want to write your own [page model](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/page-model.html), you can use one module with two classes:

Page models:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export class PageModel1 {
    constructor () {
        this.h1  = Selector('h1');
        this.div = Selector('div');
    }
}

export class PageModel2 {
    constructor () {
        this.body = Selector('body');
        this.span = Selector('span');
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
import { PageModel1, PageModel2 } from './models';

const pm1 = new PageModel1();
const pm2 = new PageModel2();

test(`Recreate invisible element and click`, async t => {
    await t.click(pm1.div);
    await t.click(pm1.h1);

    await t.click(pm2.body);
    await t.click(pm2.span);
});
```

It's just a question of organizing your code, so you can write it in the manner suitable for you.