# Cannot import an exported class from a typescript file

Tags: typescript

I have a class exported from a typescript file called `foo.ts`

```
export default class Foo{
}
```

And I'm trying to import it in another file in the same directory

```
import {Foo} from './foo';
```

Which gives me an error

```
Module '"foo"' has no exported member 'Foo'.
```

I've looked around online to solve this, but closest I've got is this github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16475 which is still unresolved at the time of writing.

Am I missing something obvious here? Shouldn't this be valid code?

Comment: you may refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export

Comment: The answer to that question makes a strong argument against using default exports, that could be a good practice to adopt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the options to export/import things:

## Default Export

```
// foo.js
export default class Foo{
}
// bar.js
import Foo from './foo'
```

## Named Export

```
// foo.js
export class Foo{
}
// bar.js
import {Foo} from './foo'
```

---

Have a look at the above and you can see that you've mixed the two approaches in the wrong way.

Comment: Bingo! Is there any reasoning behind not allowing the import of default exports by name? It seems quite nonsensical to me.

Comment: @MarkoKacanski There is no much nonsense, however the default export is considered by some people (including me) as an antipattern. So use named exports and be happy!

Comment: Have things changed in the JS world?
I get "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND" when using Named or Default export.
Adding the ".ts" extension to the import, I get "ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION".
My importing file is an mjs file inside a Nodejs project. Is that a different story?

Comment: Maybe in my case the story is different and this question is quite old, so I posted my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324758/err-module-not-found-when-importing-a-class-into-an-mjs-file-in-a-nodejs-envir