# 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' when importing a class into an mjs file in a nodejs environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am confused between these different ways to use JavaScript (modules vs CommonJS). I understand that I have to use modules because I use nodejs (or because I used type "module" in my package.json). So this is the structure of my small project:

```
api.js
functions/
         api_functions.mjs
         token_handler.ts
         token_handling.js
         token_handling.ts
```

Note: I use api_functions.mjs because thus I can import these functions as a module. I actually only want to have one file handling the token, but these are different tries (thought the name or the file type might matter). All of these three lead to the same result:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '<path>\src\functions\token_handler' imported from <path>\src\functions\api_functions.mjs
```

api_functions.mjs imports the TokenHandler (note the trial and error) and would like to use it:

```
// import { TokenHandler } from './token_handling';
import { TokenHandler } from './token_handler';
const token_handler = new TokenHandler();
```

The various token_x files export the TokenHandler class:

```
export class TokenHandler { ... }
```

I also tried with the default export and import (and yes, no mixture as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931691/cannot-import-an-exported-class-from-a-typescript-file/53931922)), but with the same result.

Why does JS think my TokenHandler class is a module in the first place?

Why can it not find it?

Bonus question: Is there any way I can turn my api_functions.mjs into an TypeScript file? I really prefer TypeScript (probably too much Java in my history ...).