# How can I make typescript export backward compatible with module.exports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I had a node.js module defined like so:

```
function sayHi(){
  // do something
}

module.exports = sayHi;
```

and imported using:

```
const sayHi = require('./sayHi.js');
```

as I switch to typescript I had created `sayHi.ts` as so:

```
function sayHi():void {
  // do something
}

export default sayHi;
```

which allows me to import from other `.ts` files using:

```
import sayHi from "./sayHi";
```

However, legacy `.js` files need to be updated to  `require('./sayHi.js').default` exported property now.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? ES6 imports + ES5 require?

```
tsconfig.json
---
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "lib": [], /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "checkJs": false, /* Report errors in .js files. */
        "declaration": true, /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
        "declarationMap": true, /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
        "sourceMap": false, /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        "outDir": ".", /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
        "rootDir": ".", /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
        "importHelpers": true, /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
        "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "moduleResolution": "node", /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but it might help address the issue. `export default sayHi` is often avoided in favor of `export function sayHi() {}` for many of the reasons listed here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html and here is a question related to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
function sayHi(){...}

exports = sayHi
```

this worked with both `import sayHi from "./sayHi"` and `const sayHi = require("./sayHi")`