# Why can't I `import {}` from `export default {}` in typescript

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a `typescript` file:

```
#util.ts
export default {name: 'name'}
```

I import it from another file:

```
import {name} from './util'
```

It fails to compile with the error `util has no exported member name`. How should I import it in `typescript`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `util.ts` file exports a *default export*, while you are requesting a *named export*. You must change your import to request the default export:

```js
import name from './util';
```

See the difference [in this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#syntax).

If you want to access the value of the `name` field consider using a *named export* in your `util.ts`:

```js
export const name = 'name';
```

or:

```js
const name = 'name';

export {
  name,
}
```

and then import with:

```js
import { name } from '/util';
```

Comment: then I have to access it by `name.name`?

Comment: Ahh, I see. You are confusing [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Unlike nodes `require()` you cannot destructure during import. I will edit my answer.