# Typescript class export from one module and import in another

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module, export

I have the following source tree:

```
/project/
  |- src/
      |- moduleA
          |- index.ts
          |- classA.ts (with a public function doSomething())
      |- moduleB
          |- classB.ts
```

`moduleA` `index.ts`:

```
export * from './classA'
```

`moduleA` `classA.ts`:

```
export default class ClassA {
    public doSomething(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    }
}
```

and `moduleB` tries to import `classA` in order to use `doSomething()`:

```
import {classA} from 'moduleA'
```

Error when `npm run build` in `moduleB`:

```
routes/api.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"moduleA"' has no exported member 'ClassA'.

2 import { ClassA } from 'moduleA';
           ~~~~~~~~~
```

What do I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please export class without default keyword.
Try this:

```
export class ClassA {
  public doSomething(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

  }
}
```

Then, import:

```
import { ClassA } from 'moduleA';
```

`var classA = new ClassA();` (or you can use it by injecting ClassA)

If you want to use method of `ClassA`

```
classA.doSomething(req, res, next)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're declaring classA as `default`. When you do so, the import should look like `import ClassA from 'moduleA'`.

Please check this post if you want more information

[Typescript export vs. default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305954/typescript-export-vs-default-export)