# what is the different between `import * from ''` and `import * as "" from""`?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am using javascript with webpack4 and babel7. I am confused about using `import * from ''` and `import * as '' from ''`.

for below code:

```
import tbc from `tbc`
```

the `tbc` instance will have a `default` property and I have to use `tbc.default.xxx`. Based on my understanding, it should be equal to `import {default as lib } from 'lib';`. But why does it have a `default` property?

But below code will allow me to use all properties from `tbc`, such as `tbc.xxx`.

```
import * as tbc from `tbc`
```

I wonder when I should use `import * from`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between import X and import \* as X in node.js (ES6 / Babel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386631/difference-between-import-x-and-import-as-x-in-node-js-es6-babel) and [When to use “import * as Foo” versus “import Foo”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236163)

Comment: There is no `import * from '…'` syntax, only `import * as … from '…'` or `import … from '…'` (the latter of which is equivalent to `import { default as … } from '…'`).

Answer (score 2):

file - nums.js

```
export let one = 1;
export let two = 2;
```

file - index.js

```
import {one, two} from "./nums";

alert( `${one} and ${two}` ); // 1 and 2
```

file - index.js
You can import all values at once as an object import * as obj, ex:

```
import * as numbers from "./nums";
alert( `${numbers.one} and ${numbers.two}` ); // 1 and 2
```