# Can't do a default import in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I changed **tsconfig.json** by adding this properties

`"esModuleInterop": true,
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,`

in order to be able to import a npm package `import * as ms from "ms";`

But I still get this error

```
This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

If I change with `import ms from "ms"`, then it works fine with the compiler but not with VSCode linter and  the error is

```
 can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flagts(1259)
index.d.ts(25, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.
```

As I said now is working but VSCode have a problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the default export? Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236163/when-to-use-import-as-foo-versus-import-foo).

Comment: **ms**  is an npm package

Comment: Try importing like this: `import ms from "ms";`

Comment: Thank you Lucas, it worked with the Angular Compiler, but  VSCode still does not like it

Comment: If you take out the tsconfig.json property `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,`, can you import it using the * syntax?

Comment: Nope. And Is weird because If I setup typescript compiler I can make it work with this props

Comment: I had to change `tsconfig.app.json` in order to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how the package declared the export, you can still import using the default import:

```
import ms from "ms";
```

Comment: And how can I get over the linting error from VSCode, other then using @ts-ignore?

Comment: You can try using the node import: `let ms = require("./ms");`
For more info [check this out](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7185#issuecomment-354566288)

Answer (score 86):

`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

This flag solved problem, but it should be added to **compilerOptions** section of tsconfig.json

Comment: This solution worked for me on NestJS !

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 12; installing angular-d3-cloud and @types/d3-cloud

Answer (score 58):

You can just do something like this

```
import * as printJS from 'print-js'
```

Answer (score 25):

If you have this error trying to import localforage into angular 9, I used this (Angular 9.1.12, Typescript 3.9.6):

**npm install localforage**

**// tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true, <----------------------------add this
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true <----------------------------and this
  },
}
```

**// any component or service**

```
import * as localforage from 'localforage';

constructor() {
    localforage.setItem('localforage', 'localforage value');
    setTimeout(() => {
      localforage.getItem('localforage').then((e) => {
       console.log(e);
      });
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout( async () => {
      const RES = await localforage.getItem('localforage');
      console.log('RES', RES);
    }, 10000);
  }
```

Comment: worked after moving under compilerOptions  in the //tsconfig.ts like below "compilerOptions": { "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true, "esModuleInterop": true}

Comment: be careful adding the `"esModuleInterop": true`, it can break things like `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Answer (score 4):

it works perfectly importing all from the package module
example :

`import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';`

if this doesnt work make sure you are have successfully installed the package type

Answer (score 1):

Having the error message

> This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

on a typescript import rule for an Angular component :

```
import { something } from 'amodule';
```

in node_modules/@types/amodule/index.d.ts,  I found this code :

```
declare module 'amodule' {
   export = something;
}
```

and changed it to :

```
declare module 'amodule' {
    export default something;
}
```

the import rule in the angular component was changed to :

```
 import something from 'amodule';
```

and the error message is gone and the imported module can be used as expected.

Comment: Hacking someone else's modules is not recommended. Perhaps this is just a workaround to see something work, but not guaranteed to work in long term. What happens, for instance, the node_modules is git ignored and you do an `npm install` later?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to tsconfig.json

And you must save the changes by running this command line in the terminal:

```
tsc --p tsconfig.json
```

Comment: adding it to `angularCompilerOptions`

Answer (score 0):

could be fixed by putting

> export default

instead of

> export =