# export * as bar VS export { default as bar }

Tags: javascript

What are the differences between

```js
export * as bar from 'foo'
```

and

```js
export { default as bar } from 'foo'
```

---

In my particular case, I've tried both of the followings, they all work, wonder the underlying differences between them.

```js
// echarts v5.0.0
export * as ECharts from 'echarts/lib/echarts.js'
export { default as ECharts } from 'echarts/lib/echarts.js'
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  // "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
}
```

Comment: They are [absolutely not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32236163/1048572). They *might* have the same result depending on what `foo` exports (or further, what your transpiler or module loader does with it) - please post that as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between import X and import \* as X in node.js (ES6 / Babel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386631/difference-between-import-x-and-import-as-x-in-node-js-es6-babel)

Comment: @marzelin It helped, but it didn't cover the `export * as` syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one exports **all named exports and default export** from `foo` as `bar`:

```js
export * as bar from 'foo'
```

This one **only exports default export** from `foo` as `bar`:

```js
export { default as bar } from 'foo'
```